# Add an entity into existing entity position C# EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a database table:

```
Correlation
------------
JobId (PK),
SomeId (PK),
Order (PK),
MapGuid
```

I am trying to add a new Correlation (1, 1, 1) into existing Correlation table. The order of existing entities will be updated after Add. The existing entity at (1, 1, 1) will be updated (1,1,2).

However, on add, I get an error:

> The instance of entity type 'Correlation' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for `{'JobId', 'SomeId', 'Order'}` is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

relevant piece of Code:

```
if (actionType == ActionType.Create)
{
_unitOfWork.Repository<Correlation>().Insert(
              new Correlation
              {
                JobId = jobId,
                SomeId = someId,
                Order = order,
                MapGuid = newGuid,
              });
}
if (actionType == ActionType.Update)
{
    // update the title, description, imagefile.
    var coors = _unitOfWork.Repository<Correlation>()
                          .Get()
                          .Where(a => a.JobId == jobId && a.SomeId == someId && a.Order = order)
                          .FirstOrDefault();

          // set updated values 
          if (coors != null)
          {
          coors.Order = newOrder;
          }
      }
}
```

How can I add a new entity and then update existing entities at the same time.

Comment: The item state is being tracked, so when you call it you either need to look at using AsNoTracking(), or setting the state to detached? I had a similar issue to this the other week.

Comment: I do new Object. That is equivalent to being detached. isnt it?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clever with this and use a Computed Value? Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-or-update

Comment: `Generic Repository` is an *anti*pattern when you use an ORM like NHibernate or EF, as it tries to replicate the ORM's *low* level workings. Try using EF *alone* - what would you do? You'd create the object and store it in a variable. Then you'd add it to the DbSet. Then you'd modify it **without calling SaveChanges first**. Then you'd go on and add/modify other objects. When you finished you'd call `SaveChanges` only once and EF would generate the SQL statements for all changes in a single transaction. How would you do *that* with this generic repository? What would you gain?

Comment: As for the error itself it probably points to **two** other bugs - long-lived contexts and mutable primary keys. Mutable primary keys are a *serious* problem. That primary key is the only way to identify a specific record. You can't have two rows with the same primary key in the database, or two objects with the same PK values in a context. *Don't* use a mutable field like `Order` as the primary key. If you want to store multiple versions for an entity, calculate and assign the new `Order` value *before* saving

Comment: As for long-lived contexts, a DbContext is essentially a UoW. It keeps track of changes but only persists them at the end, when `SaveChanges` is called. `SaveChanges` itself uses a transaction internally, so it doesn't need any extra transactions. A DbContext is *not* meant to be reused in different *business* transactions or operations.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own question.

"The order of existing entities will be updated after Add. The existing entity at (1, 1, 1) will be updated (1,1,2)."

EF cannot insert a 1,1,1 when one already exists, and in your case the context knows about it. Even if the context didn't know about it (detached) you'd still get potential errors about inserting duplicate rows.

The main issue you have here is in your design. You potentially have an existing record (1,1,1) that you want to insert a new (1,1,1) and make that old record (1,1,2). Of course that needs to cascade because any existing (1,1,2) would become (1,1,3) and so-forth. The design issue is that you've made the PK of your table a composite key, and a meaningful key at that, as opposed as a dumb, simple, meaningless key. Keys are an identifier to a unique record. By design they should be immutable. (Cannot change)

To solve your issue the easiest way, change your table design to:

```
Correlation
------------
CorrelationId (PK) Identity 1,1
JobId (FK),
SomeId (FK),
Order,
MapGuid
```

And create an index on JobId + SomeId + Order since that will be significant for whatever this table will probably be used for. You can even enforce no duplicates, but I'd be wary of that because there may be no guarantee that EF will update the existing rows before inserting the new one.

Now, when you go to do an insert:

```
var existingCorrelations = context.Correlations.Where(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SomeId == someId).ToList();
foreach(var correlation in existingCorrelations)
{
   correlation.Order += 1;
}

context.Correlations.Add( new Correlation { JobId = jobId, SomeId = someId, Order = 1, MapGuid = mapGuid } );
context.SaveChanges();
```

In this case the Correlation has a PK called correlation ID. It is a meaningless key in the sense that none of your business logic will ever depend on it except as an identifier for this specific record. Now you can change the Order of an existing record.

Agreeing with Panagoitis about the Generic repository. I don't see it adding anything of value in your case, it helps to keep things simple.  The above example should be easy enough to revert back to the repository pattern if that is what you're stuck with.

If you cannot change the data schema, then you're pretty much painted into an ugly little corner of the bathroom. It can still be worked around, but that's a lot more fiddley work loading existing records and moving the non-key data along the chain all the way to a new row on the end, and replacing the first row with the new data. (don't go there, really. :)